# Django TypeError: argument must be int or float when trying to access model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a very odd error any time I try to access one of my models. All other models work fine.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
class Hop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    aa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True, default = 10)
    b = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, blank=True)
    user_created = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I run Hop.objects.all() I get the following error. Never seen this before.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 250, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 72, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1044, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
  File "C:\Users\corym\Documents\Projects\mybrewlab vue\Backend\mybrewlabapi\env3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\operations.py", line 285, in converter
    return create_decimal(value).quantize(quantize_value, context=expression.output_field.context)
TypeError: argument must be int or float
```

Comment: Your error is coming in views.py, please post your vies.py here.

Comment: Did you by any chance have changed your model (like changing a `CharField` to a `DecimalField`)?

Comment: My error is not coming from views.py I am running Hop.objects.all() directly into shell. I haven't changed the model at all, although I recently upgraded django from 1x to 2x

Answer (score 4):

Simply delete all files in the migrations folder(accept `__init__.py`) of that app and also delete `db.sqlite3`. And then make migrations again and also create superuser again after migrations.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already created a model and the migration. And inserted data according to them.
Then you changed the rule in model and tried to access one of the record you already created. In this case, you will get the errors like you said:

[image]

So the answer is, you need to update your data with new model rules

*Happy to hear that you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It helped me.

Comment: This works: But first makemigrations > migrate and then syncdb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, but exporting the data and re-importing fixed the error. Must have been an invalid character on either the AA or B column.

Answer (score 0):

I was converting a `CharField` to `DecimalField` and encountered this error.  In one of the objects, I had a an alphabetic character.  I change this field to only contain numeric characters and the change worked, I didn't have to delete any of the data or migrations.

From: `ordered_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=128)`

To: `ordered_quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=4)`